# Maven not packing sound resources into JAR

Tags: java, maven, audio, resources, pom.xml

I've been a while trying to figure this out, but to no avail :/

This is my POM part

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>ATComApp.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>"src/main/resources"</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>"*/*.wav"</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.lanterna</groupId>
        <artifactId>lanterna</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and when I build the project it runs but finds no sound:

the code for the sound part is:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        File ostFile = new File(Constants.OST_PATH);

        if (!ostFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("OST File not found.");
            return;
        }

        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(ostFile);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Sound error.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
```

When I run with the IDE it runs fine, and when I package it runs but not the sound, prints my string "OST File not found." ... when I open the JAR with archive manager the resources folder isn't there.

Does anyone have a clue on why this is happening?
Big thanks!

Comment: Can you share where Constants.OST_PATH points to. Also in assembly plugin i use **/file.ext to denote with files to include/exclude without exact paths.

Comment: Sure,  OST_PATH = "./src/main/resources/Scandroid - The Force Theme (Star Wars Cover) (mp3cut.net).wav"; made the change you suggested, but didn't work :/

Comment: ./src/main/resources is path when you are working in IDE, but when packaged is usually on root. Try "classpath:filename.wav". Also i would suggest to open your archive with 7z and check the structure.

Comment: When I open the Archive I only have <firstpackagename>, META-INF and dependency related stuff on the archive root, manifest is in META-INF so the resource is not even in the jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is convention-driven. I.e., you don't need to include the `<resources>` section in your pom. Just place the WAV files under `src/main/resources/YOUR_PACKAGE/` and load them using the class loader.

If

```
/src/main/java/com/yourorg/MyClass.java
         |
         /resources/com/yourorg/sounds.wav
```

then you can write (untested):

```
package com.yourorg;

import ...

public class MyClass {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // look up resource in the class path, which resides in the same package
            URL ostFile = MyClass.class.getResource("sounds.wav");

            if (ostFile == null) {
                System.out.println("OST File not found.");
                return;
            }

            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(ostFile);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Sound error.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but just wanted to point out that later this getResource() method solved my problem! Many thanks, merry christmas!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to identify files within a .jar, you need to use `URL`, not `File`. An IDE is able to use `File`, as all the files are located in visible directories. But once the resource is within a jar, the `File` command will no longer work.

IDK enough about Maven to comment about why the resource was not jarred. But when I compile programs at the CLI, I have to add a manual step of coping resources into the compiled program's file system. AFAIK, `javac` does not do this. (There may be CLI options to `java` that can provide this but I haven't learned them if there are).